# Get memory address

Tags: c, pointers, memory, call

How do we return the address of the memory region by using a call function as such:

```
// memory_region malloc'ed before this
uint64 address = get_memory_region_address (memory_region);
printf(">> memory_region (address) = 0x%lX\n",  address);   
printf(">> memory_region (address) = %p\n",  address);  

uint64 get_memory_region_address (int* memory_region) {
    uint64* address_of_memory = 0;

    address_of_memory_region = (uint64) memory_region;

    return address_of_memory;  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "address of memory region" ? If `memory_region` was malloc'ed then it *is* the address for the that region. Your function `get_memory_region_address()` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Just to get the address. It is for specific use. 
Can you tell me how to return the address?

Comment: You have asked this question today already and got some answers. But I don't see you have employed them.

Comment: Can you provide a working code, @EugeneSh.?

Comment: Why are you posting fake code that does not compile?

Comment: Asking the same question twice does not make it more suitable. Do you actually read the comments and answers?

Comment: Did you even run a working program to make sure it returns the correct address?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan

`void designate_protected_memory_region(int* memory_region, int size_of_memory_region, uint64 address_of_protected_region_start, int size_of_protected_region) {
 uint64* address_of_memory_region_designated_start = 0;
 
 *address_of_memory_region_designated_start = (uint64) memory_region;
 printf(">> address_of_memory_region_designated_start (address) = 0x%lX\n",  *address_of_memory_region_designated_start);
 printf(">> memory_region (address) = 0x%lX\n",  memory_region); 
/**/
`


}

Comment: It is solved.

I just forgot to add `&` before memory_region at call, such as get_memory_region_address (&memory_region);

    `uint64 get_memory_region_address (int** memory_region) {
    uint64 address_of_memory_region = 0; 

    address_of_memory_region = (uint64)* memory_region; 
 printf("address_of_memory_region (start) = 0x%lx\n", address_of_memory_region);
 
    return address_of_memory_region;  
}`

Thanks for your virtuous patience.

Answer (score 2):

The correct integral type that is guaranteed able to store a pointer is `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`.

*7.18.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers*

*The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: `intptr_t`*

*The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: `uintptr_t`*

Unfortunately, those types are optional

Your code should be :

```
uintptr_t get_memory_region_address (int* memory_region) {

    address_of_memory_region = (uintptr_t) memory_region;

    return address_of_memory;  
}
uintptr_t address = get_memory_region_address (memory_region);

printf(">> memory_region (address) = %p\n",  (void *) address);
```

If you want to control the formatting of the address, you can either convert to `uintmax_t` of to `ptrdiff_t`

```
printf(">> memory_region (address) = %0xjX\n",  (uintmax_t) address);
```

or

```
printf(">> memory_region (address) = %0xtX\n",  (ptrdiff_t) address);
```

References :

- `ptrdiff_t`: 7.17 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`
- `uintmax_t`: 7.18.1.5 Greatest-width integer types `<stdint.h>`
- formatting: 7.19.6 Formatted input/output functions and specifically 7.19.6.1 The fprintf function §7

Answer (score 2):

This defintion:

```
uint64 get_memory_region_address (int* memory_region)
{
    uint64* address_of_memory = 0;
    // ...
    return address_of_memory;  
}
```

does not make any sense. You are declaring `address_of_memory` as *pointer* to some integer type, and then returning it as integer of that type.

There are essentially two ways to get a memory address of an *object pointer*.

#### Format specifier `%p`:

Simply print it as:

```
printf(">> memory_region (address) = %p\n",  (void *) memory_region);
```

This cast to void pointer is needed to ensure maximum portability. The `printf()` is variadic function, and its arguments (besides `fmt`) are subject to *default argument promotions*. This is means that if on some implementation:

```
sizeof(void *) != sizeof(int *)
```

holds, then it would issue an *undefined behavior* (strictly speaking it was UB even earlier).

#### Convert pointer's value into  integer type:

There is one portable way, using `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`. Both are *optionally* defined in `<stdint.h>`. This way, you could get memory address as:

```
uintptr_t get_memory_region_address(int *memory_region)
{
    return (uintptr_t) memory_region;
}
```

then print it as:

```
uintptr_t address = get_memory_region_address(memory_region);
printf(">> memory_region (address) = " PRIXPTR "\n",  address);
```

or even simpler as:

```
printf(">> memory_region (address) = " PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) memory_region);
```

Comment: it is still returning 0.

Comment: @UrsaMajor: It may return `0`, in which case `memory_region` is a _null pointer_. You can also check this by `if (memory_region == NULL) { printf(">> memory_region is a null pointer\n"); }`. Note that some functions from standard library return `NULL` to indicate special circumstances. For instances `malloc` indicates allocation failure in such way.

Comment: It only returns a 0 if I call the function, if I do this, it works:

`void create_memory_region(int* memory_region, int size_of_memory_region, uint64* address_of_memory_region_designated_start, uint64* address_of_memory_region_designated_end) { 
 memory_region = (int*) malloc (size_of_memory_region * sizeof(int));
 *address_of_memory_region_designated_start = (uint64) memory_region;
 *address_of_memory_region_designated_end = (uint64) (memory_region + size_of_memory_region - 1);
 printf("address_of_memory_region_designated_start (address) = %p\n", *address_of_memory_region_designated_start);`

Comment: However, I require that in a certain call function structure for some reasons.

So the malloc did work, but when I pass it to that call function structure, it returns a 0.

Comment: @UrsaMajor: I see, but you haven't described it in your question as such and it should be edited to reflect this important matter (for the future, don't put long code here - nobody reads it). Anyway, the problem is function argument `memory_region` is a _local copy_ of pointer, that you have passed into function. This local copy can be modified inside function, but this has _nothing_ to do with original pointer. The solution is modify argument into `int** memory_region`, and all subsequent occurences of `memory_region` into `*memory_region`, that are inside function's body.

Comment: Could you show me a sample code? Outside the call function. 
 int* memory_region = (int*) malloc (size_of_memory_region * sizeof(int));

the malloc is ok.

Thanks, grzegorz

Comment: Thank you, @Grzegorz

It is solved.

I just forgot to add `&` before memory_region at call, such as get_memory_region_address (&memory_region);

    `uint64 get_memory_region_address (int** memory_region) {
    uint64 address_of_memory_region = 0; 

    address_of_memory_region = (uint64)* memory_region; 
 printf("address_of_memory_region (start) = 0x%lx\n", address_of_memory_region);
 
    return address_of_memory_region;  
}`

Thanks for your virtuous patience.

Answer (score 0):

if `memory_region` is a pointer to a previously allocated memory, its value should already be the address of its first byte.

Try:

```
uint64 address = (uint64) memory_region;
```

I guess i should mention that `NULL = (void*) 0` as defined by standard C library. This `0x0f` address will always raise a segmentation fault error if you try to read/write it as a pointer, which is why it's named as such: The Null, the IfThisPointerVariableHasMeRunAwayFast, the WantASegFaultJustReadMe value

Comment: Hi Emisor, it still returns a zero.

Comment: `NULL == (void*) 0` is true, not `NULL = (void*) 0`.

Comment: I meant that NULL is defined as such in the standard C's .h files. Why would i need to cast on a logical comparison

Comment: It only returns a 0 if I call the function, if I do this, it works:

`void create_memory_region(int* memory_region, int size_of_memory_region, uint64* address_of_memory_region_designated_start, uint64* address_of_memory_region_designated_end) { 
 memory_region = (int*) malloc (size_of_memory_region * sizeof(int));
 *address_of_memory_region_designated_start = (uint64) memory_region;
 *address_of_memory_region_designated_end = (uint64) (memory_region + size_of_memory_region - 1);
 printf("address_of_memory_region_designated_start (address) = %p\n", *address_of_memory_region_designated_start);`

Comment: However, I require that in a certain call function structure for some reasons.